# Greenplum download dump to local cluster in parallel

Tags: jdbc, parallel-processing, data-warehouse, greenplum

*Is there any more effective way to fetch the whole Greenplum's dump than doing it through multiple JDBC connections to master node?*

I need to download the whole dump of Greenplum through JDBC. To do the job quicker I am going to use Spark parallelism (fetching data in parallel through multiple JDBC connections). As I understand, I will have multiple JDBC connections to Greenplum's single master node. I am going to store the data  at HDFS in parquet format.

Answer (score 3):

For parallel exporting, you can try gphdfs writable external table.
Gpdb segments can parallel write/read External sources.

http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4340/admin_guide/load/topics/g-gphdfs.html

Comment: thank you for answer! But writable external tables supports only CSV format, am I right? Is there any way to change format? I don't want to write separate CSV parser. Moreover, it's a question of what is quicker - 1) download through JDBC or 2) fetch CSV  and save it on your cluster and than parse it

Comment: gphdfs supports parquet file. http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43110/admin_guide/load/topics/g-hdfs-parquet-format.html
if you want to use spark to read csv, dataframe or dataset both can read csv directly.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can use Greenplum-Spark connector to parallelize data transfer between Greenplum segments and Spark executors.

This greenplum-spark connector speeds up data transfer as it leverage parallel processing in Greenplum segments and Spark workers.  Definitely, it is faster than using JDBC connector that transfer data via Greenplum master node.

Reference:
http://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/100/index.html